# Using multiple deliminators for javascript .split function

Tags: javascript, regex, time, split

I am using the split function below to get a times value:

**12:00**

I now want to include another .split value (*period*):

**12.00**

I discovered I could use **regex** to achieve this but am failing to get a working result.

**WORKING**

```
var time = time.val().split(':')
```

**FAILING (REGEX)**

```
var time = time.val().split('/:|\./')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is a type in itself in javascript, no need to put it quotes. Your code looks for a literal `/:|\./`.

Also, `:|\.` is `[:.]`.

```
'12.00'.split(/[:.]/);
```

outputs

```
["12", "00"]
```

Comment: A negligent oversite on my account. Thanks for spotting the obvious. Cheers Robin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this.

```
var time = time.val().split(/\.|&/)
```